# react native redirection with URL pattern

Tags: javascript, express, react-native, passport.js, expo

I am trying to add *facebook* and *google* authentication in my *react native app*. All this operation is done on server (*ExpressJS*) using [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport). On success I want to redirect with url pattern as below

```
AppName://login?data=somejson
```

I have registered a scheme in expo's app.json as mentioned at this link
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/linking.html and my json looks as below

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My App",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "sdkVersion": "21.0.0",
    "privacy": "public",
    "scheme": "AppName"
  }
}
```

In the same link it says that if you want to open app in expo in development mode then link should be something as below

```
exp://wg-qka.community.app.exp.direct:80/+
```

I have changed my server code to redirect with above pattern but it still doesn't work. I am able to open browser and login but that's pretty much. Nothing happens after that even though I have added event listener for this case

```
exp://wg-qka.community.app.exp.direct:80/login?data=somejson
```

My App.js code for react native. I am expecting event listener to be triggered but nothing happens

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', this.someFunction);
Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
  // some operation
});
```

Comment: Same exact issue here...

Answer (score 1):

[Expo Desktop example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAESd.png)

The correct link will be generated in your Expo desktop. Then everything works.
You can just do `` console.log(`${Expo.Constants.linkingUri}`) `` somewhere (e.g. where you are initiating the app) and see which linkingUri is currently being used. In documentation it's not imho clear. Took me a while to find out as I'm using terminal to run my app.

EDIT: for auth, there is also AuthSession component available: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it is like this 
         exp://wg-qka.@{your-username}.{your-scheme}.exp.direct:80/+